# Python - Replace character not working

Tags: python, replace, escaping

I am running a script through python that inserts data into a database. I can insert several rows; however, if I try to insert a row that has a single quote in it, it gives me an error:

```
sName = "Jim O'Connor"
```

returns the error:

```
ProgrammingError: ('42000', "[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression ''Jim O'Connor')'. (-3100) (SQLExecDirectW)")
```

I have tried to use the replace function, but it never turns out quite how I need it to.

```
sName = sName.replace("'","\'")
```

returns `Jim O'Connor`

and

```
sName = sName.replace("'","\\'")
```

returns `Jim O\\'Connor`

What I need is `Jim O\'Connor`

Thanks in advance!

**Update:**
The article posted as an effort to mark this as a duplicate in no way answers the question of why I am getting this error. It is a question on parameterization (which I did not ask about). Although I understand that the answer may be to use parameters, asking why an escaped SQL statement is not working is entirely different then asking how to parameterize. I will review the article to determine if using parameters fixes the issue.

Comment: Don’t manually try to escape stuff for SQL. Use parameterized queries.

Comment: Yes, do what @poke says. http://security.stackexchange.com/a/127657/1427 - *"We're in 2016! SQL injections are a thing of the past unless you use insecure code. Prepared statements separate the query from the data, making it impossible for the data to affect the query."*

Comment: In response to your update, in this question you are not *“asking why an escaped SQL statement is not working”*. You are asking how to perform some escaping to be used within an SQL statement. The answer to that is: you don’t; you should be using parameterized queries instead. When using parameterized queries and you are still having difficulties, you can open a new question in which you ask about the actual query you’re trying to execute.

Comment: @poke - Thanks for the information, that is exactly what I was wondering. I am working now to parameterize it, and will open a new thread if/when I have another question. Thanks again!

Comment: btw `Jim O\\'Connor` is correct. Try `len("O'C".replace("'","\\'"))` and `len("\\")` to see why.